# Undefined err variable

Tags: go

As a Go "newb" I'm not sure why I'm receiving the errors **undefined err** and **undefinded user** in the console when compiling the program.

I have:

```
if req.Id == nil {
    user, err := signup(C, c, &req)
} else {
    user, err := update(C, c, &req)
}

if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, err)
    return
}

doSomethingWith(user)
```

I realise I could probably declare the `err` and `user` variables before the conditional block but I would like to know why this doesn't work. Is it something to do with creating two new variables in one go?

**UDPATE**
Getting in a bit of a mess with this.

I've now got:

```
user := core.User{}
if req.Id == nil {
    user, err := signup(C, c, &req)
} else {
    user, err := update(C, c, &req)
}

cleanUser(&user)
```

and my errors now are **user declared and not used**. I'm not tackling the **err** part at the moment but I'm unsure why I'm getting errors about the user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the scope of the `err` variable you're creating: it is only in scope (and therefore valid/referable) till the end of innermost block in which you declared it.

Spec: [Declarations and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

> The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and **ends at the end of the innermost containing block**.

When you declare it before the `if` statement, then it will be in scope till the end of the container block which also includes the 2nd `if` where you test the `err` variable, so that is ok.

**UDPATE:**

Update to your update: you used a [Short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) which creates new variables because you used it in a new block. You haven't used these new variables (only the "other" `user` declared outside the inner block) hence the compile time error "*user declared and not used"*.

Solution is simple: simply declare both variables before the `if` and don't use short variable declaration but simply [assignment](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

```
user := core.User{}
var err error

if req.Id == nil {
    user, err = signup(C, c, &req)
} else {
    user, err = update(C, c, &req)
}

if err == nil {
    cleanUser(&user)
}
```

Or using one line to declare both `user` and `err`:

```
user, err := core.User{}, error(nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - getting in a bit of a mess though so updated my question. Any code sample would be much appreciated