# Golang undefined: err

Tags: variables, go, scope, compiler-errors

I am trying out the simple following conversion program.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strconv"
)

func main(){
  var numStr string="2213"
  var numVar int64
  numVar,err=strconv.ParseInt(numStr,10,64)
  fmt.Println(numVar)
}
```

The above throws the following compilation error.

```
undefined: err
```

Then I tried to define the err, error variable.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strconv"
)

func main(){
  var numStr string="2213"
  var numVar int64
  var err error
  numVar,err=strconv.ParseInt(numStr,10,64)
  fmt.Println(numVar)
}
```

But then the compiler throws the following error this time.

```
err declared and not used
```

I referred to the following stackoverflow question [Undefined err variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628568/undefined-err-variable) but did not get complete understanding of the behavior and hence asking the question here.

Comment: In go, if you declare variable then must be used.

Comment: See these options op1 and op2: https://play.golang.org/p/z3PlcAIrd4e

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You declare `err`:

```
var err error
```

and then you assign something to it:

```
numVar,err=strconv.ParseInt(numStr,10,64)
```

but then you don't look at `err` or access it. Just assigning something a value doesn't count as using it, you have to look at `err`:

```
numVar,err=strconv.ParseInt(numStr,10,64)
if err != nil {
  // Complain or something here
}
```

If you really don't want to bother with the error, then say so by using the blank identifier:

```
numVar, _ = strconv.ParseInt(numStr, 10, 64)
```